# Using a tkinter GUI, I want to run the program without it freezing so that the user can interact with the program while it runs

Tags: python, tkinter

I apologise for the long code and confusing inputs, I had to do some stuff in retrospect. This program counts (types the number) to a certain number (capped at 100 because I got lazy) and it designed for a game (hence the / and space, enter inputs). Everything works well, you can try it out in notepad.

However, when running the program everything freezes until the counting is complete. I've heard about threading although I'm not able to understand it, unfortunately. What I want to achieve is that the program can run and the user can still interact with it while it is running and pause/stop the program if they so desire. I've setup a naive STOP button but that doesn't work when its running and also closes the program which is unideal, as I'd rather just pause or cancel counting.

```
from pynput import keyboard as keyboard3
import time
import keyboard as keyboard2
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
import sys


num2words = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five',
            6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 10: 'Ten',
            11: 'Eleven', 12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen',
            15: 'Fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen', 18: 'Eighteen', 19: 'Nineteen'}
num2wordsTens = ['Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Forty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety']

def exitProgram():
    sys.exit()

def num2text(numb,caps):
    """
    :param numb: number to convert to text
    :param caps: True/False capital returns
    :return: Take the integer and returns text equivalance
    """
    if 0 <= numb <= 19:
        if caps:
            return (num2words[numb]).upper()
        else:
            return (num2words[numb])
    elif 20 <= numb <= 99:
        tens, remainder = divmod(numb, 10)
        if caps:
            return (num2wordsTens[tens - 2] + ' ' + num2words[remainder] if remainder else num2wordsTens[tens - 2]).upper()
            #Can add "+ '-' +" if we want a hyphonate it.
        else:
            return num2wordsTens[tens - 2] + ' ' + num2words[remainder] if remainder else num2wordsTens[tens - 2]
    elif numb == 100:
        return "One Hundred"
    else:
        print('Number out of implemented range of numbers.')


keyboard = keyboard3.Controller()


def jumpingJacks(maxNumb, initDelay, intervalDelay, caps, grammar):
    """
    :param maxNumb: Max number for the list of numbers
    :param initDelay: Initial delay before starting
    :param intervalDelay: Delay between sending messages
    :param grammar: If true, add fullstop.
    :return: none
    """
    time.sleep(initDelay.get())
    numberInterval = list(range(1, maxNumb.get()+1))
    for integer in numberInterval:
        keyboard.tap('/')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if grammar:
            keyboard.type(num2text(numberInterval[integer-1], caps)+'.')
        else:
            keyboard.type(num2text(numberInterval[integer-1], caps))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard2.press('enter')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard2.press('space')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard2.release('space')
        time.sleep(intervalDelay.get())

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x200")

numJJ = tk.IntVar(value=10)
intDelay = tk.IntVar(value=5)
JJDelay = tk.IntVar(value=1.5)
capsCheck = tk.BooleanVar()
grammarCheck = tk.BooleanVar()

frame_top = tk.Frame(master=window)
frame_1 = tk.Frame(master=frame_top)
labelt1 = tk.Label(master=frame_1, text="Number of JJ")
entryt1 = tk.Entry(master=frame_1, width=5, textvariable=numJJ)
labelt1.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=10,pady=(5,1))
entryt1.pack(side=tk.TOP)

frame_2 = tk.Frame(master=frame_top)
labelt2 = tk.Label(master=frame_2, text="Initial Delay (s)")
entryt2 = tk.Entry(master=frame_2, width=3, textvariable=intDelay)
labelt2.pack(side=tk.TOP,padx=10, pady=(5,1))
entryt2.pack()

frame_3 = tk.Frame(master=frame_top)
labelt3 = tk.Label(master=frame_3, text="JJ Delay (s)")
entryt3 = tk.Entry(master=frame_3, width=3, textvariable=JJDelay)
labelt3.pack(side=tk.TOP,padx=10, pady=(5,1))
entryt3.pack()


frame_4 = tk.Frame(master=frame_top)
labelt4 = tk.Label(master=frame_4, text="Capslock?")
checkt4 = tk.Checkbutton(master=frame_4, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, variable=capsCheck)
labelt4.pack(side=tk.TOP,padx=10,pady=(5,1))
checkt4.pack()

frame_5 = tk.Frame(master=frame_top)
labelt5 = tk.Label(master=frame_5, text="Grammar?")
checkt5 = tk.Checkbutton(master=frame_5, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, variable=grammarCheck)
labelt5.pack(side=tk.TOP,padx=10, pady=(5,1))
checkt5.pack()

frame_bottom = tk.Frame(master=window)

jumpingJacks = partial(jumpingJacks, numJJ, intDelay, JJDelay, capsCheck, grammarCheck)
toggleButton = tk.Button(master=frame_bottom, text="Begin", command=jumpingJacks)
toggleButton.pack()

ExitButton = tk.Button(master=frame_bottom,text="Stop",command=exitProgram)
ExitButton.pack()

frame_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
frame_2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
frame_3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
frame_4.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
frame_5.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

frame_top.pack()
frame_bottom.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: why you used num2words list. there is a module in python called num2words which convert number string to word string. your code may become shorter by using that

Comment: `threading` is the ideal solution for you (and perhaps the only). FWIW, `threading` is actually easier than what it looks to someone who doesn't use it. 
Once you get a hold of it, there is no coming back ;) Look up some tutorials on threads, consult the docs, Do NOT try to implement your use cases straight up. Firstly experiment with threads. Create programs for fun. and You'll be able to implement your use case easily after that. Good Luck.

Comment: @PSSolanki is right. You must implement threading in your code